# How to get state outside a react component (using redux tool kit)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on a sizable react-redux application. Without using a react component or useSelector hook, how can I get the state from the React Redux Toolkit store?

I have already used useSelector hook in other places in my app which is working well but now I need to make use of the state value outside my react component. I can't use useSelector outside a functional component.

I found this method online but I am not sure if it is safe to use it OR there is a better route to solve this problem.

```html
import store from "./store"
const { var1, var2 } = store.getState();
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: This is actually safe. you can use this as a source of your data.  But to be more clear can you please explain what are the safety parameters that you have in mind?

Comment: Hi @TalhaFayyaz. I have used import store from "./store"  but I realized that the state values are all empty. But when I checked with redux dev tools I see all my state's values. Any reason why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

### You can use a selector with getState

```js
const var1 = var1Selector(store.getState())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure I understand what you mean by use a selector with getState.  Do you mean useSelector hook?

Comment: a selector that you use like this with `useSelector`: `const var1 = useSelector(var1Selector);` can be use like this with just the state `const var1 = var1Selector(store.getState())`

Comment: Maybe I can add this precision in the answer as it might not be clear enough ?